# getJSON callback not executed in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, getjson

A callback function in jQuery getJSON never gets called in Internet Explorer 9, despite the fact that the requested file has been loaded successfully (I've checked in the Network tab).

```
var user = 1;

$.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
});

var fileUrl = "/path/to/file.php";

var fetchQuestions = function(kanji)
{    
    alert('this fires');
    $.getJSON(
        fileUrl,
        {action: "get-q", kanji: kanji, user: user},
        function(json)
        {
            alert('this does not fire');
            questions = json;
            currentItem = json.info.kanji;
            showStart(json.info);
        }
    );
};
```

- the data returned is valid json
- it works fine in all other browsers
- the requested file does get loaded with 200 OK and Content-Type application/json
- there are no console.log() calls anywhere in the file
- there are no errors in the console (in IE9, or in any other browser)

Any ideas?

Here's the JSON returned:

```
{"info": {
                "kanji": "線",
                "meanings": "line",
                "desc": "",
                "words": [{"audio":"/jp/files/audio/words/線_せん","kanji":"線","en":"line","jp":"せん"},{"audio":"/jp/files/audio/words/地平線_ちへいせん","kanji":"地平線","en":"horizon","jp":"ちへいせん"},{"audio":"","kanji":"内線","en":"phone extension, indoor wiring, inner line","jp":"ないせん"},{"audio":"","kanji":"直線","en":"straight line","jp":"ちょくせん"},{"audio":"","kanji":"脱線","en":"derailment, digression","jp":"だっせん"},{"audio":"","kanji":"線路","en":"line, track, roadbed","jp":"せんろ"},{"audio":"","kanji":"水平線","en":"horizon","jp":"すいへいせん"},{"audio":"","kanji":"新幹線","en":"shinkansen","jp":"しん・かん・せん"}]
            },
"spots": [{"kanji":"\u5c71","rand_ind":"32"},{"kanji":"\u68ee","rand_ind":"47"},{"kanji":"\u5225","rand_ind":"76"},{"kanji":"\u98ef","rand_ind":"127"},{"kanji":"\u98f2","rand_ind":"175"},{"kanji":"\u9b5a","rand_ind":"203"},{"kanji":"\u5354","rand_ind":"252"},{"kanji":"\u9752","rand_ind":"265"},{"kanji":"\u9032","rand_ind":"302"},{"kanji":"\u805e","rand_ind":"310"},{"kanji":"\u8a08","rand_ind":"311"},{"kanji":"\u4ea4","rand_ind":"362"},{"kanji":"\u4f1a","rand_ind":"367"},{"kanji":"\u53d7","rand_ind":"404"},{"kanji":"\u5973","rand_ind":"463"},{"kanji":"\u90e8","rand_ind":"469"},{"kanji":"\u4e16","rand_ind":"476"}],
"known": "月,後,前,生,?"}
```

Comment: Have you tried it with `$.ajax` instead of `$.getJSON`? And how do you know that the callback never gets called? Have you actually tried to put `console.log` inside of it? Maybe there is an issue with `showStart`, not the callback?

Comment: Switching to ajax unfortunately does not solve the problem. And of course, I've used alert() outside and inside the callback function and it is only the one inside the function that never fires.

Comment: That's very, very interesting. Maybe IE has problems with parsing JSON you are sending? Can you show us how this JSON looks like?

Comment: json_encode'ing the "known" part of the returned JSON solved the problem! Looks like IE has some issues with unicode characters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json_encode'ing the "known" part of the returned JSON solved the problem! Looks like IE has some issues with unicode characters.